# How did bells become a part of Buddhist ritual?

Tags: traditions, monasticism, rituals

Bells seem to be pervasive throughout Buddhist ritual. I get the impression that many monasteries ring a large bell in the morning, and other monasteries still ring regular bells throughout the day to encourage mindfulness. Most meditation apps on smartphones have a bell-ringing sound.
**Where did this come from? What other usage do bells have in Buddhist ritual? Are there references to bells in canonical texts?**

Answers from all sects appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

A "bell" is mentioned in the [Visuddhimagga](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visuddhimagga).

In [this translation](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/nanamoli/PathofPurification2011.pdf) it says,

> 89. And, though sometimes not separate, *applied thought* is the first impact of
>       the mind in the sense that it is both gross and inceptive, **like the striking of a bell**.
>       *Sustained thought* is the act of keeping the mind anchored, in the sense that it is
>       subtle with the individual essence of continued pressure, **like the ringing of the
>       bell**. *Applied thought* intervenes, being the interference of consciousness at the
>       time of first arousing [thought], like a bird’s spreading out its wings when
>       about to soar into the air, and like a bee’s diving towards a lotus when it is
>       minded to follow up the scent of it. The behaviour of *sustained thought* is quiet,
>       being the near non-interference of consciousness, like the bird’s planing with
>       outspread wings after soaring into the air, and like the bee’s buzzing above the
>       lotus after it has dived towards it

A 'bell' is even mentioned [in the Dhammapada](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/kn/dhp/dhp.10.budd.html),

> **134**. If, like a broken gong, you silence yourself, you have approached Nibbana, for vindictiveness is no longer in you.

Answer (score 1):

At least in Sri Lanka bells are used as a "call" to gather everyone at the temple to signal the start of an event.

In some cases like in Siripada as a means to announce how many times you have visited.